# autowired doesnt work in junit spring mvc 5

Tags: java, spring, junit

I was trying to test my web application but @autowired annotation doesn't work and the field is set to null. Please help.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { AppConfig.class, WebSecurityConfig.class, MvcWebApplicationInitializer.class},
loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
@PersistenceContext
@Transactional(transactionManager = "hibernateTransactionManager")
@TestExecutionListeners({})
public class NewsDaoTest {

    @Autowired
    private NewsService newsService;

    @Test
    @Rollback(true)
    public void testAddArticle() {

        Article article = new Article();

        article.setLink("test");
        article.setTitle("Title");

        assertTrue(newsService.create(article));
    }

}
```

Comment: Remove `@TestExecutionListeners({})`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare `@TestExecutionListeners({)}` on a test class that does not extend any other test class annotated with `@TestExecutionListeners` you are effectively telling Spring to load only your Listener classes, when you actually want to use a combination with the default listeners from Spring (e.g., the `DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener` which adds support for dependency injection of beans from the ApplicationContext).

so removing should load all required dependencies by autowired..

```
RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { AppConfig.class, WebSecurityConfig.class, MvcWebApplicationInitializer.class},
loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
@PersistenceContext
@Transactional(transactionManager = "hibernateTransactionManager")
public class NewsDaoTest {
```